# background color for header div not working

Tags: css

I've just started learning CSS and am following a YouTube tutorial [Learn CSS in 12 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0afZj1G0BIE), however I am stuck at minute 4:49 - the title should show a blue background but mine doesn't?

```
<head>
<title>My website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.cs
</head>
```

and on my stle.css sheet I have:

```
#header {
    background-color: #66CCFF;
}
```

I expected the area behind 'title' to be blue when I view in browser.

Comment: First of all, consider taking considerably longer than 12 minutes to learn CSS. Secondly, the `#header` is styling the div with the id `header` in his index.html.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.cs` - that is not even complete and error-free HTML, so most likely your stylesheet did not get embedded at all here. (If that is your actual code.)

Comment: _“I expected the area behind 'title' to be blue when I view in browser.”_ - what area “behind title” to begin with? The `<title>` element is not displayed _inside_ of the rendered web page you are looking at, but shown in the browser title bar - that is nothing you could “style” to begin with. My serious suggestion would be: Get off “the ’tubes”, and go _read_ through a proper tutorial that explains some of the basics.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Don't worry, I'm not expecting to learn in 12 minutes, I'm going to be coding for 5 hours/day for next 2 years to try and get a fundamental grounding in it.I am very realistic. I have joined a Skill-share course to begin with and the question I had for you was the very first tiptoe into coding, I wanted to get a quick overview that's all. I appreciate your instructions.

Comment: After retyping the code, it now works. As you pointed out, the code line <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.cs was not ended correctly. I don't know how that happened but correcting it seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a `header` [tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp) to make it turn blue using css.

In css, you can apply style to a tag by simply copying its name (here `header`, not `#header`), and apply style to `id` or `class` by indicating their `#name` (for id) or their `.name` (for classes).

The `title` tag display a text in tab and program title (like [here](https://up.l3m.in/file/1560770700.png)).

Your html code should look like this (I closed the `link` element):

```
<head>
<title>My website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<header>My blue text</header>
```

And your css:

```
header{
    background-color: #66CCFF;
}
```

If you want to learn css, you can find some [fantastic](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html) [tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics) :)

Comment: Nice :) But concerning your learning technique, I don't think videos are great to learn css. The best way for me was the tryit editors of w3c (like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self)), because as soon as you learn something you have access to complete code and you can mess it up to understand how it really works :) - You can also use some [great](https://www.sublimetext.com/) [free](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/fr/) tools who can point out the mistakes like the css-related one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try by closing the link rel=stylesheet tag completely, and actually calling div id header in body, and defining height of that header if you don't have any content in it or you won't be able to see it.

As @metaDesign mentioned, you should consider taking a lot longer than 12 minutes to learn CSS...

```css
#header {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>My website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
  
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the issue. I actually retyped the whole thing and it worked. Honestly I don't see any difference but am happy it worked. Regards the 12 minutes, the way I learn is to first get a quick and dirty overview of a subject, then will start on my skillshare course and books I have. Fairly confident I'll be decent in 2 years.

Comment: That is not the best way to do it, atleast when you have 50000 files and active 200k pages on 4 different languages, like a company I'm working for. You have to be careful because even one wrong letter and the whole page won't show(assuming that you're using PHP). You can become super web designer in 20 minutes, if you have superpowers and so on, but 2 years is also nothing in coding because you have to learn every day and you can't know everything.

Comment: I totally agree. When I said 2 years, that is just an estimate of the time I expect to be able to get to the initial level of competency. I don't want to work for others, I just want to build my own website with CMS. As with all things in life, we never stop improving if we continue to try!